# How to split a list-column in a Pandas Dataframe based on a condition on the elements of the list?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame with one column, say:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"combined_list": [["Netherlands|NL", "Germany|DE", "United_States|US", "Poland|PL"], ["Netherlands|NL", "Austria|AU", "Belgium|BE"], ["United_States|US", "Germany|DE"]]})
```

I want to create two columns from the `combined_list` column:

- One containing al the normal country names (So everything before the last occurence of `|`)
- One column containing all 2 letter abbreviations (The length of these is always 2) , so basically all remaining text after the last occurence of `|`

The resulting Dataframe should look like this:

```
countries                                      abbreviations
[Netherlands, Germany, United_States, Poland]  [NL, DE, US, PL]
[Netherlands, Austria, Belgium]                [NL, AU, BE]
[United_States, Germany]                       [US, DE]
```

How to achieve this?

I know if the column of the Dataframe would simply be one string, I could use various string split functions to achieve it, but can't find anything for columns of lists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
df_out = pd.DataFrame(
    df["combined_list"]
    .apply(lambda x: list(zip(*[s.split("|") for s in x])))
    .tolist(),
    columns=["countries", "abbreviations"],
)
print(df_out)
```

Prints:

```
                                       countries     abbreviations
0  (Netherlands, Germany, United_States, Poland)  (NL, DE, US, PL)
1                (Netherlands, Austria, Belgium)      (NL, AU, BE)
2                       (United_States, Germany)          (US, DE)
```

---

To have lists in the columns:

```py
df_out = pd.DataFrame(
    df["combined_list"]
    .apply(lambda x: list(map(list, zip(*[s.split("|") for s in x]))))
    .tolist(),
    columns=["countries", "abbreviations"],
)
print(df_out)
```

Prints:

```
                                       countries     abbreviations
0  [Netherlands, Germany, United_States, Poland]  [NL, DE, US, PL]
1                [Netherlands, Austria, Belgium]      [NL, AU, BE]
2                       [United_States, Germany]          [US, DE]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use explode and then convert to a dataframe, with groupby.agg

```
out_cols= ["countries", "abbreviations"]
out =(df['combined_list'].explode().str.split("|",expand=True)
      .groupby(level=0).agg(list).set_axis(out_cols,axis=1))
```

---

```
print(out)

                                       countries     abbreviations
0  [Netherlands, Germany, United_States, Poland]  [NL, DE, US, PL]
1                [Netherlands, Austria, Belgium]      [NL, AU, BE]
2                       [United_States, Germany]          [US, DE]
```

Comment: very informative solution! (and by far the best imho) but is the second `agg(list)` a typo?

Comment: @MustafaAydın Ahh, yes it is, thank you :) I will edit that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
df2['Countries'] = df.apply(lambda row:[row['combined_list'][i].split('|')[0] for i in range(len(row['combined_list']))], axis=1)
df2['Abbreviations'] = df.apply(lambda row:[row['combined_list'][i].split('|')[1] for i in range(len(row['combined_list']))], axis=1)

print(df2)

                                       Countries     Abbreviations
0  [Netherlands, Germany, United_States, Poland]  [NL, DE, US, PL]
1                [Netherlands, Austria, Belgium]      [NL, AU, BE]
2                       [United_States, Germany]          [US, DE]
```